# How do I get multiple pages of result from themoviedb api and store in state in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, themoviedb-api

I am stuck in trying to get page 2 results in the same state... Please take a look at my code and help me.

```
    const URL = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?api_key=#&language=en-US&page=1';
    const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);

    const testapi = async() => {
      const response = await fetch(urlGiven);
      const data = await response.json();
      setMovies(data.results);
    }
```

Now I am trying to another request to the api with &page=2 and set that data to append my current movies const... I tried doing setState([...movies, data.results]) again for:

```
https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?api_key=#&language=en-US&page=2
```

PAGE 2 data but that did not render correctly in react native flatlist.

For example, like this:

```
const secondCALL = async() => {
    const response = await fetch(page2URL);
    const data = await response.json();
    setMovies([...movies, data.results]);
}
```

How do I go on about appending page 2 data right after page one's original that is set in here: setMovies(data.results);

My flatlist set up, for example ( only showing the relevant part)

```
<FlatList
            data={movies}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add ... at data.results, otherwise you will have [movie1, movie2, [movie3, movi4]]

```
const secondCALL = async() => {
   const response = await fetch(page2URL);
   const data = await response.json();
   setMovies([...movies, ...data.results]);
}
```

Comment: I tried doing this but my flatlist still only shows the first api call result... Do you know how to get the result of both of these calls in flatlist to show when rendering the state movies data?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the spread operator synthax to expands the content of data.results.

consider this example :

```
const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
const [page, setPage] = useState(1);


const getMovies = async () => {
  try{
    let req = await fetch(`'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?api_key=#&language=en-US&page=${page}`);
    let data = await req.json();
    // spread the content of movies and data 
    setMovies([...movies, ...data]);
  }catch(err){
   throw err
  }
}

return (...)
```